InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Guid'. ASP.NET
I have a web app where basically everything works. Today I wanted to extend my IdentityUser with ApplicationUser so the user can have FirstName, LastName and ProfilePicture.
The problem comes here. When I register a User with the Application User everything works and the user is signed in the Db. But when I try to access Account/Manage or Account/Login it pops with this error:

I'm posting my applicationUser class, my login and register and manage view and cs.html
namespace OnlineShop.Data.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
        public string? ProfileImgUrl { get; set; }
    }
}

ApplicationDbContext:
namespace OnlineShop.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>, Guid>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {

        }
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderProduct> OrdersProducts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ShoppingCart> ShoppingCarts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ShoppingCartProduct> ShoppingCartsProducts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Gender> Genders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ClothingType> ClothingTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}

Program.cs
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
}).AddRoles<IdentityRole<Guid>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

Register.cshtml.cs
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.
#nullable disable

namespace OnlineShop.Web.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IUserStore<ApplicationUser> _userStore;
        private readonly IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser> _emailStore;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _userStore = userStore;
            _emailStore = GetEmailStore();
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public class InputModel
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string ProfileImgUrl { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }


        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = CreateUser();

                user.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
                user.LastName = Input.LastName;
                user.ProfileImgUrl = Input.ProfileImgUrl;

                await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }

        private ApplicationUser CreateUser()
        {
            try
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance<ApplicationUser>();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Can't create an instance of '{nameof(IdentityUser)}'. " +
                    $"Ensure that '{nameof(IdentityUser)}' is not an abstract class and has a parameterless constructor, or alternatively " +
                    $"override the register page in /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml");
   

     }
    }

    private IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser> GetEmailStore()
    {
        if (!_userManager.SupportsUserEmail)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The default UI requires a user store with email support.");
        }
        return (IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser>)_userStore;
    }
}

}
Login.cshtml.cs
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.
#nullable disable

namespace OnlineShop.Web.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Log the attempted email to help with debugging
                _logger.LogInformation("Attempting to sign in user with email: {Email}", Input.Email);

                // Lookup user by email
                var userEmail = Input.Email;
                var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userEmail);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User not found for email: {Email}", Input.Email);
                }

                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}


According to your code, I create a new Razor page application and customize the Identity User like you, after using the migration command to generate the database, the primary key of the AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles table primary key id uniqueidentifier data type (SQL Server), Then I checked your register and login code, they all works well and can't reproduce the problem.

InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to
type 'System.Guid'.

This error usually occurs in ASP.NET Core Identity when there's a mismatch between the data types defined in your application's identity model and the types of data stored in the database.

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>

and

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>, Guid>
{


From the above code, we can see you have already customized the Identity Model uses Guid for the primary key. Then, after migration success, check the table definition in the database, we can see the AspNetUsers table should have the Id column as uniqueidentifier (SQL Server) or an equivalent type for Guid in other databases.

So, please check your data table definition in the database.

In the database, if it still using the nvarchar datatype (by default), might be you forgot to enable migration after customizing the Identity User. Then, to solve this issue, you need to generate and apply a new migration (use add-migration XXX and update-database command) to reflect this change in your database, make sure the data type matches.
[Note] When enable migration, you might meet the "The object 'PK_AspNetUserTokens' is dependent on column 'UserId'" error, to solve this issue, you can delete the folder "Migration" and add migration again. Refer to this thread.
Besides, you can also try to delete the existing database and delete the folder "Migration" and add migration again, then your code should work with the new database.
